# R or Python code for returning the largest number of consecutive 1s from a binary vector

Tags: r, python-3.x

I'm new to coding and have started with R and Python. I want to write a code to solve the following problem.
My question is: How do I write a function in R or Python which takes a vector of length L consisting only of 0s and 1s  as input and returns the largest number of consecutive 1s from the vector as an integer, e.g. the function takes [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1] and returns 3.

Comment: General rule of thumb - please do add some of your efforts along with asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can use `rle` to get the `max` number of consecutive 1's.

```
consecutive_1 <- function(x) {
   with(rle(x == 1), max(lengths[values]))
}

vec <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
consecutive_1(vec)
#[1] 3

vec <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)
consecutive_1(vec)
#[1] 4
```

---

If we want to check for length, we can add an additional condition

```
consecutive_1 <- function(x, L) {
   if(length(x) != L)
     stop('Vector is not of length ', L)
   with(rle(x == 1), max(lengths[values]))
}
consecutive_1(vec, 9)
#[1] 3

consecutive_1(vec, 10)
```

> Error in consecutive_1(vec, 10) : Vector is not of length 10

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. One clarification, how do I satisfy the condition that it's a vector of length L.

Comment: @user12869559 I updated the answer to check for that additional condition.

Comment: Besides, your code given above displays this error in R Studio: Error in rle(x == 1) : object 'vec' not found

Comment: @user12869559 `vec` is the vector/array that has 0's and 1's value in it.